# Why does 'for' loop without termination condition print value '0' over & over again forever?

Tags: loops, for-loop, if-statement, boolean

Without the if statement is an infinite loop printing 0 to an infinite number.
Why adding the if statement prints 0 and 0 again and again if ?

```
for (int zz=0; ;zz++ ) {    //with the if statement 
if(zz==0)System.out.print(zz+"zz \n");
//System.out.print("....");
```

}

```
for (int zz=0; ;zz++ ) {    //without if statement.
System.out.print(zz+"zz \n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention the language, but your variable `zz` does not have infinite range (no variable of any type does). So once it counts up past its highest representable value, it (probably, depending on the language and whether it will cause some sort of exception for overflows) will "wrap" to its lowest value, which would be a very negative number since your variable is signed. Then it will continue counting up until it reaches `0` again, when it will print. In your code, it will continue doing this forever. Surely you noticed that it prints the zeros much slower than the "without if statement" version prints its numbers? That's because `zz` holds the value `0` very seldom; e.g. once every 4 billion iterations.

Comment: it's java. Very smart answer and it does everything as you said. I'm just trying to simplify your explanation. Thank you @phonetagger.